# Excel question regarding the unique formula"

Tags: excel, excel-formula

[image]I inserted formula of unique in D column and wanted only unique values but I am getting "0" also in my output.
How to remove "0" from the output?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ckdO4.png)

Comment: Try using : `=UNIQUE(FILTER(D:D,D:D<>""))` since you have selected the whole column it includes the blank rows as well, therefore returning the zero, one other way could be changing the range into a table and use the `UNIQUE()` Function as it will take only the rows in the structured references.

Comment: I used UNIQUE(D:D,,1) which worked for me...

Comment: No that will not give exact output needed, it will return those values which have appeared once. But OP is asking for unique values from a range, so there can be duplicates or unique as well !

Answer (score 1):

So based on my comments above, OP needs to use the following :

[image]

---

• Formula used in cell `F2`

```
=UNIQUE(FILTER(D:D,D:D<>""))
```

---

Another alternative way:

```
=UNIQUE(TOCOL(D:D,1))
```

---

Using the one in below will not work:

```
=UNIQUE(D:D,,1)
```

---

Will exclude the other duplicate texts which also needs to be returned as unique.

---

Comment: I'd rather use TOCOL here instead of using filter thus processing an entire column.

Comment: Hi, @JvdV Sir I posted that as well in screenshot lemme update it, also OP;s other questions I have posted your formula.